# Disallow objects to be rendered from specific cameras during playtime

Tags: game-engine, camera

Can I order specific cameras to not render objects during play-time?

And how?

Comment: You can dynamically toggle visibility of objects. So when you switch a camera you toggle the visibility to your needs.

Comment: First thing I thought was layers , masking etc. I forgot the simple solution. Make it an answer if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically toggle visibility of objects. So when you switch a camera you toggle the visibility to your needs.